# How to upload pictures from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, graphics

When I take a picture with my iPhone 4 and I want to upload them to a site like craigslist or etsy, the upload or browse button is always gray so it doesn't allow me to do it. I try going to my desktop but the pictures arent there.  I have the cloud and wifi enabled but the pics don't go onto my computer. So I try emailing them to myself through gmail but I cant get the pics to completetly come off the email when I download them. I am at a complete loss and this is way more complicated than it should be, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

As other posters speculated, iOS 6 now supports uploading pictures through standard file upload forms.

Answer (score 0):

The press has said that this fall's release of iOS 6 will provide a standard file-upload element will work as you expect, allowing you to choose or take a photo to upload. See [this article](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/13/ios-6-safari-media-uploads/) for more information.

[image]

Comment: And how does this solve the problem? It's highly unlikely that Angie already uses an iOS version which isn't available to the public yet.

Comment: Is this disclosed out of NDA?

Answer (score 0):

I was as frustrated as you about the problems regarding inter-device file transfer. Not being able to upload files from the browser is the climax (iOS 6 may come to rescue here), but until then try my Open Source software [cross copy](http://cross-copy.net) to get the photos from your device onto your desktop:

1. install and open the App "cross copy"
2. on your computer browse to http://cross-copy.net
3. enter the same codeword
4. pick your photo on the phone, it will instantly appear as downloadable item on the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Check out the web browser iCab Mobile for iPad and iPhone. This seems to be currently the only full featured browser for the iOS platform which supports file uploads. There are a few limits though, but I can successfully upload photos on facebook, Flickr, Craigslist and many other pages.